# Visual Studio 2010 Full and ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I've installed full version (not RC nor Beta) of Visual Studio 2010, a then setup within Web Platform Installer 2.0 announce me that I need to install MVC 2.0, so i did it.

When I want to create project "MvcWebApplicationProjectTemplate" in VS I have following message:

**error: this template attempted to load component assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.2.0, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. For more information on this problem and how to enable this template, please see documentation on Customizing Project Templates.**

Any idea how to fix it?
Do you think that Web Platform Installer 2.0 might have corrupted this template?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS 2010 comes with MVC2. I am guessing installing it again using WPI made it corrupt. Try uninstalling the MVC2 install (the one through WPI) and then repair the VS 2010 RTM install.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, problem was with WPI, it corrupted VS 2010 templates for ASP.NET MVC 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently if you installed MVC2 RC2 after VS2010 there is an issue.  Try the following link:

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/10/installing-asp-net-mvc-2-rc-2-on-visual-studio.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 repair solved my problem.